# accessing and changing data.frame variables by condition

Tags: r

the following `df` exemplary shows the sunshineduration on a hourly basis. 
During nighttime (21:00-02:00) the raw-values have been set to `NA`.

```
YY MM DD HH ssd282 ssd867
1962  1  1  0     NA     NA
1962  1  1  1     NA     NA
1962  1  1  2     NA     NA
1962  1  1  3      0      0
1962  1  1  4      0      0
...
1962  1  1 19      0      0
1962  1  1 20      0      0
1962  1  1 21     NA     NA
1962  1  1 22     NA     NA
1962  1  1 23     NA     NA
```

I want to set these `NAs` to `0` using a condition which describes something like:

```
if(df$HH < 4 & df$HH > 20) {
    df[,(5,6)] = 0
}
else {
keep all values
}
```

I don't really know how to achieve this in `R`. Does anybody know how to do this without changing the structure of my `df`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `&` instead of `|`?  You're trying to find rows where `HH` is between 3 and 21, right?  They are all `<= 21`  or `>= 3`.  That's not the extent of your problems, but it's a major one.

Comment: yes, you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop through the columns 5 and 6 (`lapply(..`), and replace the values based on the condition using `ifelse`

```
df[,5:6] <- lapply(df[,5:6], function(x) ifelse((df$HH <4 | df$HH > 20 ) & is.na(x),0 , x))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for your fast reply. Although your command is working, the `NAs` are not being changed to `0`. May there be something else considered when accessing `NA`Values?

Comment: Now this finally is the solution:
`df[,(5:16)] <- lapply(df[,(5:16)], function(x) ifelse((df$HH < 4 | df$HH > 20) & is.na(x),0, x))`

Comment: @M.Weeker  THanks for the feedback.  Changed that in the post.